# I want to make sure stories cannot be closed unless they are linked to a parent feature

Tags: azure-devops

In our organization, Features are a releasable object and all stories must be linked to a feature in order to be closed. Unfortunately not everyone followed this rule of thumb and I want to put a rule on the story object such that changing the state to "closed" is dependent on a parent linkage existing.
I'm not seeing any option in the rules currently based on linked items (i.e. state being set to closed is dependent on a linkage to a parent item).
Has anyone needed to get around this and can anyone suggest a method to overcome this?
I've seen a suggestion to create a custom field for users to manually check a flag that "they've already linked the story to the feature" but I would rather the system detects it automatically and to not make this annoying for my team.

Thanks in advance.

I tried creating a work-item rule for stories as such:
When Work Item state is closed, Then make required "Parent Link"
But "Parent Link" is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

There is not bult-in rule option to check whether a work item has parent linked. I also checked on Marketplace, did not find available extensions can do this.

If your projects really need this feature, I recommend you try to report a feature request on [**Developer Community**](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). That will make it more convenient for our product teams to receive and understand your ideas. And your feedback also could be helpful for us to improve our Azure DevOps products.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll go ahead and do that!